# Xamarin Form Map get break with targetSdkVersion="28"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im using Xamarin Form (last version) and if my targetSdkVersion = 28, then Xamarin.Forms.Maps will break and this error show up

```
Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.SecurityException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details> occurred
```

It will work normally with targetSdkVersion 27

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Check out https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/153354/java-lang-securityexception-in-maps

Comment: Hi , what is the nuget package version of Xamarin Forms Maps , does it be the latest ?

Comment: yes, it's the latest

Comment: nvm, the problem was solved

Comment: @lilyang Okey , if solved remember to share solution in answer , then other people will see it *.^

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28

Answer (score 0):

Update: i have fixed that by adding to AndroidManifest

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
```